# EasyMock throwing matcher error on method call recording with no matchers?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, easymock

I'm using EasyMock 3.4 and have a unit test I'm getting an error on that's pretty bizarre.

The stack trace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception usually occurs when matchers are mixed with raw values when recording a method:
    foo(5, eq(6));  // wrong
You need to use no matcher at all or a matcher for every single param:
    foo(eq(5), eq(6));  // right
    foo(5, 6);  // also right
    at org.easymock.internal.ExpectedInvocation.createMissingMatchers(ExpectedInvocation.java:51)
```

And my unit test is below as follows:

```
    @Test
    public void testAddOrUpdateGuestMessageScenario(){
        final Session mockSession = EasyMock.createMock(Session.class);
        final Query mockQuery = EasyMock.createMock(Query.class);
        final Transaction mockTransaction = EasyMock.createMock(Transaction.class);
        final GuestMessageScenarioBO guestMessageScenarioBOMock = EasyMock.createMock(GuestMessageScenarioBO.class);
        final MessageCampaignBO messageCampaignBOMock = EasyMock.createMock(MessageCampaignBO.class);
        final InboundMessageSimulatorBO inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock = EasyMock.createMock(InboundMessageSimulatorBO.class);

        EasyMock.expect(guestMessageScenarioBOMock.getInboundMessageSimulatorBO()).andReturn(inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock).anyTimes();
        EasyMock.expect(inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock.getMessageCampaignBO()).andReturn(messageCampaignBOMock);
        EasyMock.expect(inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock.getCreateDate()).andReturn(null);
        EasyMock.expect(messageCampaignBOMock.getMessageCampaignRecordId()).andReturn(1234L);
        EasyMock.expect(mockSession.get(MessageCampaignBO.class, 1234L)).andReturn(messageCampaignBOMock);

        guestMessageScenarioBOMock.setCreateDate(EasyMock.isA(Timestamp.class));
        guestMessageScenarioBOMock.setUpdateDate(EasyMock.isA(Timestamp.class));
        inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock.setMessageCampaignBO(messageCampaignBOMock);
        inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock.setCreateDate(EasyMock.isA(Timestamp.class));
        inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock.setUpdateDate(EasyMock.isA(Timestamp.class));
        inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock.setGuestBusinessRuleUsageIndicator(true);

        EasyMock.expect(mockSession.createQuery(EasyMock.isA(String.class))).andReturn(mockQuery);      
        EasyMock.expect(mockSessionFactory.openSession()).andReturn(mockSession).anyTimes();
        mockSession.close();
        EasyMock.expectLastCall();
        EasyMock.expect(mockSession.beginTransaction()).andReturn(mockTransaction);
        mockSession.saveOrUpdate(EasyMock.isA(GuestMessageScenarioBO.class));
        mockTransaction.commit();
        EasyMock.replay(mockSessionFactory, mockSession, mockQuery,mockTransaction, guestMessageScenarioBOMock, inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock, messageCampaignBOMock);
        guestMessageScenarioDAO.addOrUpdateGuestMessageScenario(guestMessageScenarioBOMock);
    }
```

The line that it's complaining about is:

```
EasyMock.expect(guestMessageScenarioBOMock.getInboundMessageSimulatorBO()).andReturn(inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock).anyTimes();
```

I understand that in EasyMock, you cannot mix matchers with actual values/objects in method calls or else it throws an error, but it's pretty clear looking at that code there is simply no matchers being used period, never mind mixed with anything as that method on guestMessageScenarioBOMock doesn't even take any parameters.

Any idea what it's complaining about?

Update: Including the @Before method

```
@Before
public void onSetup() {
    mockSessionFactory = EasyMock.createMock(SessionFactory.class);
    guestMessageScenarioDAO = new GuestMessageScenarioDAO();
    guestMessageScenarioDAO.setSessionFactory(mockSessionFactory);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way inheritance might be causing this?  Maybe EasyMock creates a matcher for a child and parent class (or an interface) and the results are different object types?

Comment: @kondrak Can you elaborate on that? guestMessageScenarioBOMock does inherit from another class but I'm not sure what to look for that would be causing this issue.

Comment: What I'm saying is you may have to be careful what you're mocking because of the possibility of something like this: http://pastebin.com/HKB4iaNX

Comment: Nope, guestMessageScenarioBOMock just simply extends another class and it doesn't look like it's doing anything like that. Any other ideas? This is really driving me nuts...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when you remove the ".anyTimes()" from the end of the line it's complaining about?

Comment: Still throws an error. It's actually very irritating just how many things I've tried and yet the issue still occurs.

Comment: Ok, but what IS the error, it's important :)

Comment: It's the exact same error, 0 matchers expected, 1 recorded.

Comment: Also should mention this mocks in question are not global mocks, so this shouldn't be an issue not calling .reset() on them in other tests.

Comment: What about if you remove that expectation?  (Essentially, I'm trying to figure out if this is the only problem or if there is something incorrect across the board)

Comment: Then it complains about EasyMock.expect(inboundMessageSimulatorBOMock.getMessageCampaignBO()).andReturn(messageCampaignBOMock); and then the next one, and then the next one, until the entire unit test is useless

Comment: So, its the same message for all of those expectations?

Comment: do you have a @Before method?

Comment: @JérémieB yes there is a before method which sets up some commonly used mocks but not the mocks in question

Comment: @AdamBronfin your issue is probably here

Comment: @JérémieB the issue is probably with the Before method? I have updated the question with my before method

Comment: I was wrong ;-) The better I can suggest is to put a breakpoint in the method `ExpectedInvocation.createMissingMatchers` and check the `matchers` property : you'll see which matcher has been registered. You can too put a breakpoint on `EasyMock.reportMatcher`

Comment: @JérémieB Even if its compiled source?

Comment: I don't know your IDE. Personally, I use Eclipse/Maven which download for me the sources of this kind of dependency - it's easy to debug any library. If you do it manually, checkout the sources of easymock from github ?

Comment: @JérémieB Some more potentially useful information: I commented out every single test except the one in question and it ran successfully. I then uncommented tests until a second failed, which was one directly above in the file. When I swapped the ordering of the two tests, it works successfully. This is absolutely driving me insane. There is no shared state between these tests, and what they do is pretty similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with the fact that in a previous test, a mocked object had a method call recorded that was not followed by an expectation.

When this happened, EasyMock attempted to match an expectation with the recorded method call, even in ANOTHER test.

```
mockedObj.doSomething();

EasyMock.expectLastCall(); //This was missing and is needed.
```

Hope this helps someone else.